# Copiar dado da linha anterior se o teste logico falhar

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estou tentando realizar uma operação com pandas, mas estou travando em uma parte, não sei se da logica ou por não saber qual a melhor função usar do python/pandas.

Imagem do meu dataframe: [image: imagem dataframe]

Código:

```
Conta = []
for i in rzBase.itertuples():
  Conta.append( i.Lançamento if i.Crédito == 'Saldo Anterior' else xxxxx)
  rzBase['Contas'] = Conta
```

Em xxxxx preciso que o valor dessa nova coluna Contas fosse copiado. Ou seja, se na coluna Crédito o valor não for Saldo Anterior, me trago o valor da linha anterior da coluna Contas.

Travei em como posso fazer isso com o pandas dentro desse looping. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Podes usar a função next com um valor por defeito para obter o valor anterior. Para criar a coluna no dataframe tens que estar fora do ciclo senão a contagem não fica certa.

```
Conta = []
for i in rzBase.itertuples():
  anterior = next(reversed(Conta), '')
  Conta.append( i.Lançamento if i.Crédito == 'Saldo Anterior' else anterior)

rzBase['Contas'] = Conta
```